# How to insert 'Empty' field in ComboBox bound to DataTable

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a combo box on a WinForms app in which an item may be selected, but it is not mandatory. I therefore need an 'Empty' first item to indicate that no value has been set.

The combo box is bound to a DataTable being returned from a stored procedure (I offer no apologies for Hungarian notation on my UI controls :p ):

```
 DataTable hierarchies = _database.GetAvailableHierarchies(cmbDataDefinition.SelectedValue.ToString()).Copy();//Calls SP
 cmbHierarchies.DataSource = hierarchies;
 cmbHierarchies.ValueMember = "guid";
 cmbHierarchies.DisplayMember = "ObjectLogicalName";
```

How can I  insert such an empty item?

I do have access to change the SP, but I would really prefer not to 'pollute' it with UI logic.

**Update:** It was the DataTable.NewRow() that I had blanked on, thanks. I have upmodded you all (all 3 answers so far anyway). I am trying to get the Iterator pattern working before I decide on an 'answer'

**Update:** I think this edit puts me in Community Wiki land, I have decided not to specify a single answer, as they all have merit in context of their domains. Thanks for your collective input.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are two things you can do:

1. Add an empty row to the `DataTable` that is returned from the stored procedure.

   ```
   DataRow emptyRow = hierarchies.NewRow();
   emptyRow["guid"] = "";
   emptyRow["ObjectLogicalName"] = "";
   hierarchies.Rows.Add(emptyRow);
   ```

   Create a DataView and sort it using ObjectLogicalName column. This will make the newly added row the first row in DataView.

   ```
   DataView newView =           
        new DataView(hierarchies,       // source table
        "",                             // filter
        "ObjectLogicalName",            // sort by column
        DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);  // rows with state to display
   ```

   Then set the dataview as `DataSource` of the `ComboBox`.
2. If you really don't want to add a new row as mentioned above. You can allow the user to set the `ComboBox` value to null by simply handling the "Delete" keypress event. When a user presses Delete key, set the `SelectedIndex` to -1. You should also set `ComboBox.DropDownStyle`  to `DropDownList`. As this will prevent user to edit the values in the `ComboBox`.

Comment: A little late in the game, but the first option worked well for me. The only thing I did different was, use InsertAt, so that my empty ("None") option appears as the first item in the combobox: hierarchies.Rows.InsertAt(emptyRow, 0);

Comment: Forgot to mention... I didn't use a DataView and bound directly to a table returned by a method, so it was already sorted correctly. InsertAt is useful in this case.

Answer (score 15):

```
cmbHierarchies.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Comment: That will show an empty item until you make a selection, it will not insert an empty item

Answer (score 9):

I usually create an iterator for this type of thing.  It avoids polluting your data, and works well with data-binding:

```
DataTable hierarchies = _database.GetAvailableHierarchies(cmbDataDefinition.SelectedValue.ToString()).Copy();//Calls SP
cmbHierarchies.DataSource = GetDisplayTable(hierarchies);
cmbHierarchies.ValueMember = "guid";
cmbHierarchies.DisplayMember = "ObjectLogicalName";

...

private IEnumerable GetDisplayTable(DataTable tbl)
{
    yield return new { ObjectLogicalName = string.Empty, guid = Guid.Empty };

    foreach (DataRow row in tbl.Rows)
        yield return new { ObjectLogicalName = row["ObjectLogicalName"].ToString(), guid = (Guid)row["guid"] };
}
```

Disclaimer:  I have not compiled this code, but have used this pattern many times.

**Note:** I have been in WPF and ASP.Net land for the last couple of years.  Apparently the Winforms combo box wants an IList, not an IEnumerable.  A more costly operation would be to create a list.  This code is really stream-of-conciseness and I really, really have not compiled it:

```
DataTable hierarchies = _database.GetAvailableHierarchies(cmbDataDefinition.SelectedValue.ToString()).Copy();
List<KeyValuePair<string, Guid>> list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, Guid>>(hierarchies.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => new KeyValuePair<string, Guid>(row["Name"].ToString(), (Guid)row["Guid"])));
list.Insert(0, new KeyValuePair<string,Guid>(string.Empty, Guid.Empty));
cmbHierarchies.DataSource = list;
cmbHierarchies.ValueMember = "Value";
cmbHierarchies.DisplayMember = "Key";
```

Comment: I am getting a "Complex DataBinding accepts as a data source either an IList or an IListSource" error, and am unable to find a conversion between IEnumerable and IList (I am in WinForms if you are used to doing this in WPF)

Comment: I have been in ASP.Net land for a while, but recall using this pattern in WPF.  I have not worked with WinForms for about 3 years.  If this wants a list then I would suggest a similar strategy, just create a list instead of using an iterator.

Comment: ASP.NET, makes sense. I do like the pattern though

Comment: how about GetDisplayTable(theDataTable).ToList() ?

Comment: I think you have to put the "cmbHierarchies.DataSource = list;" after the value & display member setters, then you'll be good. Good example. +1

Answer (score 3):

insert a blank row in your datatable, and check for it in validation/update/create

Comment: Better would be to "select" a blank row and UNION that with your real query.  That would leave your database intact.

Comment: @[BoltBait]: except that he already said he did not want to change his stored procedure

Comment: I prefer to keep UI requirements outside of the DB.

Comment: @[Coov]: so do i, but the OP's mileage may vary; obviously this is a hack!

Answer (score 2):

Cant you add a new DataRow to the DataTable before you bind it to your DataSource?

You can use the NewRow function of the DataTable to achieve this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.newrow.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I found another solution:

Just after your data table is created (before using fill), add new row and use AcceptChanges method to the table. The new record would get RowState = Unchanged, and would not be added to database, but would be visible in your datatable and combobox.

```
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Rows.Add();
    dt.AcceptChanges();
    ...
    dt.Fill("your query");
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this method based on the suggestions here by Jason Jackson:

```
private IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<object,object>> GetDisplayTable(DataTable dataTable,  DataColumn ValueMember, string sep,params DataColumn[] DisplayMembers)
{
    yield return new KeyValuePair<object,object>("<ALL>",null);

    if (DisplayMembers.Length < 1)
        throw new ArgumentException("At least 1 DisplayMember column is required");

    foreach (DataRow r in dataTable.Rows)
    {
        StringBuilder sbDisplayMember = new StringBuilder();
        foreach(DataColumn col in DisplayMembers)
        {
            if (sbDisplayMember.Length > 0) sbDisplayMember.Append(sep);
            sbDisplayMember.Append(r[col]);
        }
        yield return new KeyValuePair<object, object>(sbDisplayMember.ToString(), r[ValueMember]);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
bindingSource1.DataSource = GetDisplayTable(
            /*DataTable*/typedDataTable, 
            /*ValueMember*/typedDataTable.IDColumn, 
            /*DisplayColumn Seperator*/" - ",
            /*List of Display Columns*/
            typedDataTable.DB_CODEColumn,
            typedDataTable.DB_NAMEColumn);

comboBox1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Key";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "Value";

//another example without multiple display data columns:
bindingSource2.DataSource = GetDisplayTable(
            /*DataTable*/typedDataTable, 
            /*ValueMember*/typedDataTable.IDColumn, 
            /*DisplayColumn Seperator*/null,
            /*List of Display Columns*/
                typedDataTable.DESCColumn );
```

further down, where the Selected Value is consumed:

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedValue != null)
     // Do Something with SelectedValue   
else 
     // All was selected (all is my 'empty')
```

This will allow to display several columns concatenated in the ComboBox, while keeping the Value member to the single identifier + it uses the iterator block with the BindingSource, BindingSource might be overkill for your situation.

Сomments and suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Er, can't you just add a default item to the ComboBox after data binding?

Comment: Setting a default (via Text property) on the Combobox is overriden when the datasource is bound to the datatable.

Comment: Then add the value to the DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

I would bind the data then insert an blank item at position 0 using the ComboxBox.Items.Insert method.  Similar to what flipdoubt suggested, but it adds the item to the top.

Comment: Once the datasource of the combobox is bound to the datatable an error occurs when trying to insert.  Specifically - Items collection cannot be modified when the Datasource property is set.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar challenge.  As part of the form load event I set the SelectedIndex of the control to -1

ie

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
    this.TableAdapter.Fill(this.dsListOfCampaigns.EvolveCampaignTargetListMasterInfo);
    this.comboCampaignID.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

Effectively, the combo box is populated and the first item is selected.  Then the item is unselected.  May not be a viable solution for all cases.

Answer (score 0):

`this.recieptDateTimePicker.SelectedIndex = -1;`
this.dateCompoBox.SelectedIndex = -1;

Answer (score 0):

I have found this way:

```
    DataTable hierarchies = new DataTable(); 

    cmbHierarchies.BeginUpdate();
    cmbHierarchies.ValueMember = this.Value;
    cmbHierarchies.DisplayMember = this.Display;
    hierarchies = DataView.ToTable();
    cmbHierarchies.DataSource = table;
    cmbHierarchies.EndUpdate();

    //Add empty row
    DataRow row = table.NewRow();
    table.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0);
    cmbHierarchies.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a new row to your datatable, just bind the data to the combobox and at load set the SelectedIndex to -1. This will cause the selection to be null until the user selects an item.

I clipped this from one of my current projects.

```
        Attorney_List_CB.DataSource = DA_Attorney_List.BS.DataSource;
        Attorney_List_CB.DisplayMember = "Attorney Name";
        Attorney_List_CB.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

In order to clear the selection I usually insert a button that sets the SelectedIndex back to -1.

```
    private void Clear_Selection_BTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Attorney_List_CB.SelectedIndex = -1;  // Clears user selection
    }
```

Finally, once I validate the data on my form, if the SelectedIndex of any combobox is -1 then it is skipped, or I will generate some type of default value such as "N/A" or whatever I need under the circumstances.