# DataView Sorting After AddNew

Tags: c#, sorting, combobox, dataview

I am trying to add an initial unbound entry into a bound ComboBox. I am trying an approach very similar to the answer to the following post:

[How to insert 'Empty' field in ComboBox bound to DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199642/how-to-insert-empty-field-in-combobox-bound-to-datatable)

However, the main difference is that I have strict requirements and cannot add a row to the actual datatable (as this is used by other components). So, my solution is to add the additional row to the dataview instead of the datatable:

```
    public void FillVendorComboBox(DataSet1.VendorDataTable vendors)
    {
        //Create a custom view of the vendor table
        DataView view = new DataView(vendors);

        //Add a new row to the view with default values
        DataSet1.VendorRow vendorRow = (DataSet1.VendorRow)view.AddNew().Row;
        vendorRow.Name = "a";

        //Sort the view according to the vendor name
        view.Sort = vendors.NameColumn.ColumnName;

        //Bind the view to the combo box
        cbxVendor.DataSource    = view;
        cbxVendor.DisplayMember = vendors.NameColumn.ColumnName;
        cbxVendor.ValueMember   = vendors.IdColumn.ColumnName;
    }
```

The problem is that the sorting is not working as expected. The added value is always sorted to the end of the ComboBox:

- BC    (bound)
- Shell (bound)
- a     (added) <-- why is this sorting to the bottom?

Also please note that the VendorRow.Name is datatype System.String and VendorRow.Id is datatype System.Int32.