# Add blank row to PowerShell table when SQL query returns nothing

Tags: powershell

I'm using a PowerShell SQL query a to do a server lookup in a database as follows:

```
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
$connection.Open()
$command = $connection.CreateCommand()

$table = new-object “System.Data.DataTable”
$ServerArray = "Server1", "Server2", "Server3"

$ServerArray | ForEach-Object {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.tablename where System_Name = '$_'"
    $command.CommandText  = $query
    $result = $command.ExecuteReader()
    $table.Load($result)
}
$table | export-csv -path c:\temp\serverlookup.csv
```

This is working fine for the most part - I got all the associated info from dbo.tablename for each server match and the table is well formatted.

However, some servers may not exist in dbo.tablename, but I'd like the output to include a blank row for those.  This helps lining things up when pasting back into an Excel document.

I've been able to get the following to detect a blank / no return from the query:

```
if (!$result.Read())
```

But how do I get it to add a blank row to $table for the eventual CSV export?

Ultimately I'm trying to build a csv output with data from dbo.tablename for each server, so I'm open to other ideas for how to build that table if this isn't the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

never used this before, but you might try this. there may be more than just this line. you'll have to check the link.

```
DataTable.NewRow()
```

as shown here
[How to insert 'Empty' field in ComboBox bound to DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199642/how-to-insert-empty-field-in-combobox-bound-to-datatable)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work using the following:

```
$ServerArray | ForEach-Object {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.tablename where System_Name = '$_'"
    $command.CommandText  = $query
    $result = $command.ExecuteReader()

    if (!$result.HasRows) {
        $table.Rows.Add()
    }
    $table.Load($result)
}
```